# Flex: time how long HTTPService takes to load?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, debugging, httpservice

I am loading some XML with HTTPService in Flex. It is taking longer than I would like to load. So I want to do some trouble shooting, but in order to tell what is making a difference I need to be able to time the requests and how long they are taking.

What is the best way to time an http service to see how long it took from HTTPService.send() to HTTPService.result

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Flex, is there a way to determine how long an HTTPService.send() call takes round-trip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883668/in-flex-is-there-a-way-to-determine-how-long-an-httpservice-send-call-takes-ro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate, go here to see my previous answer to the question:

[In Flex, is there a way to determine how long an HTTPService.send() call takes round-trip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883668/in-flex-is-there-a-way-to-determine-how-long-an-httpservice-send-call-takes-ro/1884207#1884207)

Comment: Thanks, that was what I ended up doing myself as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Charles Proxy ( http://www.charlesproxy.com/download/ ). I use it daily as a main tool for monitoring Flex traffic (it even supports AMF). There's a free version with some annoyances (I think it only runs 30 min. each time you run it, and displays a popup from time to time).